# How to use scp when cygwin is used as default shell

Tags: ssh, scp, cygwin

I have installed openssh-server from optional features on a Windows machine. I can ssh and scp (I need upload only) from my Linux box; However I don't like cmd shell, so I installed Cygwin and set it as default shell for openssh-server ([configure shell for openssh](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration)). Now the ssh works but scp doesn't (again from my Linux box). scp hangs until I break it with Ctrl+c and no file is transferred. When I ran it with `-v` option, it hangs on `debug1: Sending command: scp -v -r -t /tmp/`

This behavior is 100% reproducible and switching the openssh-server shell between cmd and Cygwin.bat gives the explained results all the times.

I remember reading somewhere: the shell shouldn't echo anything or it won't work with scp, I checked ~/.bashrc and ~/.profile and didn't see anything printing out.

I tried `set TERM=linux` in Cygwin.bat but it didn't help.

I tried to find a way to distinguish scp from ssh in Cygwin.bat but couldn't find a way (my goal was to not start Cygwin64/bin/bash.exe for scp).

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I'm not sure why scp is hanging, but since you've already installed Cygwin, you might get better results by running Cygwin's ssh server, available in the openssh package.

Answer (score 1):

After I removed `--login` switch from `bash` command in `cygwin.bat` file, `scp` worked as expected.

I think removing this switch prevents `.profile` script to be executed, I couldn't find anything conflicting with `scp` in this file, so there may be other behavior changes too.